# How to replace only the first element of a List<Character> using java streams without making any changes to the rest of the list?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I am getting a List and I want to replace the first value in this list with '$' sign, So that I could use it in some place else. But i don't want the rest of the characters in the list to be misplaced or changed. It's okay to get the result as a new list.

I already tried to just use the list.add(index, value) function but it changes the order of the list. But I don't want any change to the rest of the list.

Is there any good tutorials to to learn java streams. I find it confusing to master. Thanks in advance.

If the input list is ('H','E','L','L','O') the output should be exactly like ('$','E','L','L','O').

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you show it here? Looks like you can just do something like `list.set(0, '$');`.

Comment: Do you mean [`List.set`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#set-int-E-)?

Comment: Streams aren't relevant here in any way.

Comment: Looks like an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378). Where does this `List<Character>` come from and what do you want to do with the transformed list? I never encountered a `List<Character>` in real application code…

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7452772/java-arraylist-replace-at-specific-index

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access the list using indices. If the index is zero just `map` it to a `$`, otherwise just send it to the next step of the stream processing pipeline. Finally collect it into a List. This approach is better than modifying your source container if you are using Java8. Here's how it looks.

```
List<Character> updatedList = IntStream.range(0, chars.size())
    .mapToObj(i -> i == 0 ? '$' : chars.get(i))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This problem does not lend itself nicely to be solved using Java8 streams. One drawback here is that it runs in linear time and looks we have over engineered it using java8. On the contrary, if you modify your array or list directly `chars[0] = '$';`, then you can merely do it in constant time. Moreover, the imperative approach is much more compact, readable and obviously has less visual clutter. I just posted the Java8 way of doing it, since you have explicitly asked for that. But for this particular instance, **imperative way is far more better** in my opinion. Either use an array and set the `0`th index or if you need to go ahead with a List for some reason, then consider using [List.set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#set-int-E-) instead, as stated in the comments above.

Answer (score 1):

hi you can look it the solution

```
public static void replaceCharacterList(){

        List<String> list =new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("H");
        list.add("E");
        list.add("L");
        list.add("L");
        list.add("O");
        List<String> newItems = list.stream()
            .map(value-> value.replace(list.get(0),"$") )
            .collect(toList());
      Log.d("replace list","list "+list+" new list "+newItems);
    }
```

and the output will be like this

> output: list [H, E, L, L, O] new list [$, E, L, L, O]

also for another example you can also look it to this example without Streams

https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/util/collections/replace-specific-element-of-list-example/

Comment: It gets the job done. But if we don't know what character is there in the first index we can't use this method.

Comment: @tTs I have write this code for your given example. Now i have updated the questions which will be valid for everytype character it 1st position.

Comment: Unless there’s another `"H"` in the list…

Answer (score 1):

Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57901769/11733759), but with external index

```java
AtomicInteger index = new AtomicInteger();
List<Character> newCollect = list.stream()
        .map(ch -> (index.getAndIncrement() == 0) ? '$' : ch)
        .collect(toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

You could always use the traditional array copy and validation in the replace method for the index:

```
public class Main {
  private static List<Character> replace(List<Character> chars,int index, char value) {
    Character[] array = characters.toArray(new Character[0]);
    array[index] = value;
    return Arrays.asList(array);
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Character> characters = new ArrayList<>();
    characters.add('H');
    characters.add('E');
    characters.add('L');
    characters.add('L');
    characters.add('O');
    characters = replace(characters, 0, '$');
    for (Character character : characters) {
      System.out.println(character);
    }
  }
}
```